# Django Models: Common Ancestor Inheritance & Migration

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

I thought I would *up my python game* with Django a bit by developing a large scale business app for fun. I seen the need for a **common ancestor** approach to model inheritence and tried to implement it based on the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#multiple-inheritance). However, I keep getting this very annoying Message which I'm not sure what to do with.

- **Dj Version:** Django 1.7
- **Py Version:** Python 3.4.2

**Message**

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
```

> ```
> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'businessentity_ptr' to business without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
>
> Please select a fix:
>  1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
>  2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
> ```

**Models.py**

```
class BusinessEntity(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=180)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Business(BusinessEntity):
    description = models.TextField(max_length=600)
    claimed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

What I've Tried, (which everyone will hate):

1. Deleting the DB & Re-migrating
2. setting a default value for all fields
3. Setting all fields to `null = True`

I have seen a hack around for this but I don't think it's a good approach. Maybe there is someone out there who understand Django Common Ancestors much better and point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you need BusinessEntity to be an actual concrete model that you can query? Otherwise it would be better as an abstract model, and your problem wouldn't happen.

Comment: Django inheritance for models can get messy (even with mixins instead of concrete ancestors). I regret having used it in my current project. I found a lot of corner cases the [POLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) is violated.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah, it's just abstract. There is no need to query over the BusinessEntity object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since your parent model is intended to be abstract, you should mark it as such.

```
class BusinessEntity(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=180)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

This prevents Django from creating a separate table for it, and therefore needing a `_ptr` field to point back to it from the subclass. Instead, the table for your subclass will be created to include the inherited field(s) directly.