# 'makemigrations' asks for a default with none-abstract model inheritance

Tags: python, django, inheritance, model, makemigrations

I'm trying a simple model inheritance:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Application(Product):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

'makemigrations' asks for a default:

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'product_ptr' to
>   application without a default; we can't do that (the database needs
>   something to populate existing rows).

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26780098/django-models-common-ancestor-inheritance-migration) that I could Product an abstract model with a Meta class, but I can't do that since I'm refereing it specifically in other models as an actual model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    product      = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name="comments")
```

Running 'makemigrations' when the database is removed also leads to the same issue.

Anything I can do?

Django 1.9

Comment: try changing it to this name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Blah') and try again

Comment: Does Application already exist, and you're moving it to be a subclass of Product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't explained what exactly is the change that you have made, it seems that you have changed your `Application` model to inherit from `Product` where it previously inherited from models.Model. That causes django to create a 1 to 1 mapping behind the scenes. The addition of the product_ptr which you didn't add to the model yourself enters the picture

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance

> The inheritance relationship introduces links between the child model
>   and each of its parents (via an automatically-created OneToOneField).

It's a bit tricky to add this field to a table with data during a migration because this field needs to be unique. If you are merely creatig a new model named `Application`, a value of 1 would be ok.

Comment: Thanks! removing the old migration file seemed to do the trick (at least migration-wise)

Comment: That would result in this being treated as a new model I think